# How to write Haskell BFS algorithm for the list of strings

Tags: algorithm, haskell, breadth-first-search

I try to solve "ladder" problem using Haskell. The task is to find the shortest path (if it exists) in list of the words between two words of the same length. The rule for words connection is

1. We can get one word from another with one replace (word -> cord)
2. This word (in my example "cord") should be in our list of the words

So, if we have list[word, cord, wore] and we need a ladder from wore to cord the answer will be wore -> word -> cord. I try to solve this using bfs algorithm. To get neighbours of the word I use next functions

```
--(x:xs) - letters
getChanged :: [String] -> [Char] -> [String] -> [String]
getChanged cont (x:xs) ans = 
    if length xs == 0
    then ans ++ [cont !! 0 ++ [x] ++ cont !! 1]
    else getChanged cont xs (ans ++ [cont !! 0 ++ [x] ++ cont !! 1])

--get for getChanged
divide :: String -> Int -> [String]
divide word index = [(take index word)] ++ [(drop (index + 1) word)]


--word alphabet indexToChange AnswerAcc Answer
getNeighbours :: String -> [Char] -> Int -> [String] -> [String]
getNeighbours word alphabet index answerAcc = 
    if index == length word
    then
        answerAcc
    else
        getNeighbours word alphabet (index + 1) (answerAcc ++ (getChanged (divide word index) alphabet []))

main = do
    putStrLn (unlines (getNeighbours "hello kitty" ['a', 'b', 'c'] 0 []))
```

The ladder signature is something like this

```
ladder :: String -> String -> String -> IO()
ladder word1 word2 words = do
    content <- readFile words
    let words = lines content
    let myWords = Set.fromList (filter (\x -> length x == length word1) words)
    if not (Set.member word1 myWords) || not (Set.member word2 myWords)  
    then error "Path not found"
    else do
        let b = ["1"]
        putStrLn $ unlines b
        print $ length b
```

I tried to use HashSet and HashMap but got nothing. Now I stuck on this. My question is how to write bfs for this problem?

Comment: You could probably use one of the many existing graph libraries. You need to take a list of words and produce the graph corresponding to the "connections" between those words. Your BFS algorithm (or the one from the library you use) then doesn't care about "how" you got your connections - its just a graph.

Comment: You don't provide any information about what the functions are doing...

Comment: I just want to find some clues

Comment: Some useful libraries or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So BFS is a common problem in early programming, and while its solution is not particular to Haskell, the functional nature of Haskell makes things a little trickier. So let's start with DFS:

```
import Control.Monad (msum)

dfs target tree@(Tree value children)
  | value == target = Just tree
  | otherwise       = msum $ map (dfs target) children
```

This is simple because we can recurse directly on each of the children in order (`map`) and then take the first success (`msum`). But when we do BFS we need to also thread a "context" through, and this means that we'll have to replace `map` with our own iterator:

```
bfs target tree = go [tree] where
  go [] = Nothing
  go (tree@(Tree value children) : rest)
    | value == target = Just tree
    | otherwise       = go (rest ++ children)
```

This is a valid BFS with one major flaw: In Haskell, `++` adds a conditional operation to future accesses, and here that can eventually cause O(n<sup>2</sup>) performance because they'll "stack up". This is because lists are natively "LIFO" (last-in is first-out) queues whereas you want a "FIFO" (first-in is first-out) queue.

You should still use that solution until you're sure that this flaw is noticeable. The classic solution to the flaw is to *amortize* these costs (accept O(N) costs as long as they only happen O(1/N) of the time) with two lists, but there's also a huge benefit to be gained in Haskell by making the lists themselves spine-strict so that you're not constructing huge piles of thunks:

```
-- spine-strict linked-lists
data SL x = Nil | Cons x !(SL x) deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

rev sl = go sl Nil where -- reversal
    go Nil xs = xs
    go (Cons x xs) ys = go xs (Cons x ys)

-- finite fifo queues
data Fifo x = Fifo !(SL [x]) !(SL [x])

append x (Fifo l r) = Fifo l (Cons x r)
{-# INLINE append #-}

firstRest (Fifo Nil Nil) = Nothing
firstRest (Fifo Nil r) = let (Cons x l) = rev r in Just (x, Fifo l Nil)
firstRest (Fifo (Cons x l) r) = Just (x, Fifo l r)
{-# INLINE firstRest #-} 
-- ^ we can't get rid of `rev`, which is recursive, but hopefully this INLINE 
-- will eliminate the cost to make the Maybe terms and the Haskell pair. We
-- could also manually unroll this ourselves into the case analysis of the
-- method below.

bfs target tree = go [tree] Nil where
  go bufs [] = case firstRest bufs of
                 Nothing -> Nothing
                 Just (buf, bufs') -> go buf bufs'
  go bufs (tree@(Tree value children) : xs)
     | value == target = Just tree
     | otherwise       = go (append children bufs) xs
```

Notice that we still allow a node with an infinite list of children, and notice that this overhead should usually be avoided because this code is maybe 4 times as cognitively complex as the earlier code, and may even be a lot slower for small inputs (as the overheads of `++` could well be lighter than the overheads of detecting the `rev` step and constructing new `Fifo`s.) Do things the easy way first, and if that fails we can approach the harder way.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to use it and improve my program.